# radius of action of button in css

Tags: html, css

to see if anyone can tell me why my css button has a radius of action as big around, is there any way to reduce it? 
When I put the mouse over the hand that goes in idle state goes far beyond the text of the button, I would like to reduce this area of action, but not as in css

Thank you.

CSS:

```
/*BOTONES SUPERIOR*/

#botonera-blogsuperior {
    width: 900px;
    height: 35px;
}
.texto-botones-blogsuperior {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.menu-blogsuperior,
.menu-blogsuperior ul,
.menu-blogsuperior li,
.menu-blogsuperior a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;

}

.menu-blogsuperior {
    height: 31px;
    width: 900px;

}

.menu-blogsuperior li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    height: 21px;

}

.menu-blogsuperior li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin: 25px -59px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    line-height: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url (boton-fondo-probar.png);
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  height:27px;
  width:105px;
  background-position:46px -1px;
  background-size:69px 24px;




    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;

    color: #000000;

    -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    text-align: right;
    text-align: right;
    text-align: right;
    text-align: right;
}

.menu-blogsuperior li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
.menu-blogsuperior li:last-child a{ border-right: none; }

.menu-blogsuperior li:hover > a {
    color: #FF6C6C;
}

.menu-blogsuperior ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: -109px;
    left: 0;

    opacity: 0;
    background: #1f2024;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .10s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .10s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: opacity .10s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .10s ease .1s;
    transition: opacity .10s ease .1s;
}

.menu-blogsuperior li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; }

.menu-blogsuperior ul li {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;


}

.menu-blogsuperior li:hover > ul li {
    height: 36px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu-blogsuperior ul li a {
    width: 36px;
    padding: 10px 0 1px 10px;
    margin: 0;

    border: none;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #353539;
}

.menu ul-blogsuperior li:last-child a { border: none; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="botonera-blogsuperior"><ul class="menu-blogsuperior">
  <li><a href="/blog/indice">INDICE</a></li>
  <li><a href="/blog/category/2/">DINO</a></li>
 <li><a href="/blog/category/1/">LEONES</a></li>


</ul>
</div>
```

EXAMPLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=vSgITe2BmT

Thanks !!

Comment: whats wrong with the Link? i cant open it..

Comment: @CTravel He shared the collab link instead of fiddle.

Comment: Those aren't buttons, they are links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just moved all definitions that give shape to the link from the `a` Tag to the  `li` Tag and replaced the padding with margin.

Add this to your CSS:

```
.menu-blogsuperior li {
  height:27px;
  width:105px;   
  padding: 0 0px;
  margin: 25px -59px;
  margin-right: 27px;
  background-image: url (boton-fondo-probar.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  background-position:46px -1px;
  background-size:69px 24px;
  text-align: right;
  text-align: right;
  text-align: right;
  text-align: right;
}
```

And adjust this definition in your CSS so it is exactly like mine:

```
.menu-blogsuperior li a {

  text-decoration: none;

  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;

  color: #000000;

  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: color .2s ease-in-out;

}
```

Worked for me in the fiddle.

Comment: Aquí dejo os El Ejemplo vivo, voy a TRATAR de Lo Que dices: P

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=vSgITe2BmT

Comment: I updated my answer, check the CSS if it works for you!

Comment: @user3384096 which language is this?

Comment: I get together and move all the buttons on the left :S